# How to detect the shorting/elimination of a 250 mA load in a 20 Vac circuit?

Tags: ac

**EDIT: My apologies -- I overlooked mentioning a critical fact: the "shorting" of the load is at times as fast as 50ms, and I need to detect that as well as events of the order of >1 second. At 50ms the event is too fast for a mechanical relay to react, even when buffered through an optocoupler. So I need to "capture" the event and/or "elongate" what looks like a transient, so I can then drive the relay properly rather than the relay seeing and ignoring what looks like a mere "transient".**

I need to detect the condition of a circuit. The question is how to detect the following condition:

The output of a 20 Vac (25 VA) transformer is feeding a 250 mA non-inductive load which is in series with a 10 ohm (50 watt) resistor. I have access ONLY to the 20 Vac transformer and the 10 ohm resistor. The 250 mA load at times is shorted (purposefully: as if a momentary N.O. switch were across it, and the switch were depressed for 1 second). I need to detect that "short", i.e., the momentary "elimination" of that 250 mA load that's in series with the 10 ohm resistor.

What circuit can I put across the 10 ohm resistor which will detect the momentary shorting/elimination of that 250 mA load?

If I can detect that, then I can trigger a relay, which can let me activate other things that need to be done in that situation.

Thank you.

Comment: Rectify and filter the voltage across the load. Feed it to an optocoupler. NOTE: since you have access to the 10 Ohm resistor and transformer, you actually have access to every node in the circuit. You don't have to only place something across the resistor.

Comment: Yes, I do have access to every node in the circuit! -- it's always "obvious" AFTER someone points out the "obvious" I overlooked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All that would be required is a relay with a 20 V AC coil.

[image]

**Edit # 1**

Alternately use a standard 24V DC relay and two 1N4007 diodes.

[image]

**Edit # 2**

Thanks to Bruce Abbot. Use a bridge rectifier in lieu of the two diodes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but the relay kept buzzing because of the current leakage with the load in circuit. Perhaps a different relay would not buzz?

Comment: Excellent pic! What did you use to draw the diagram? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. MS Excel and Paint!

Comment: Did you use a DC relay by any chance? Also with a coil of lower voltage?

Comment: I used an AC relay; perhaps I should try different voltages. It would seem that lower voltage would buzz even more, no? Do you think I can use a MOSFET instead of an AC relay, and have it drive on the output side 12vdc to a 12vdc relay?

Comment: That wouldn't be necessary. I've altered the schematic to accommodate a standard 24V DC relay.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it.

Comment: This will only put half cycles into the relay, 2-3 half cycles in 50ms. If you use a bridge rectifier it will get 5 half cycles in 50ms and operate more reliably.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott - Hi Bruce, Wouldn't freewheeling action sort of make up for the missing half cycle?

Comment: @vu2nan yes, but the inductance also delays the current rise. I simulated the circuit in LTspice at 50Hz with a relay coil resistance of 2.4k and inductance of 3H with 50ms switch 'on'. The coil current half-waves were only stretched from 10ms to 13ms leaving 7ms at 0V, and the average current was only 2.7mA. With a bridge rectifier the coil current was 6.5mA average, 2.3mA minimum.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott - Hi Bruce, Thank you very much for your inputs. Will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 12VAC coil relay with a ~10V bipolar TVS in series (or two Zener diodes)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRnyYQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[image]

Comment: Interesting! Thank you. (Trying to see how CircuitLab simulation works ...)

Comment: You can run my simulation and play with the circuit. This particular one runs quite slowly because we're looking at small fractions of a mains cycle over several seconds. If  you increase the time step it will run faster, but accuracy suffers. Note that I've set the peak AC voltage to sqrt(2) * 20V to get the correct RMS voltage.

Comment: Yes, thank you -- I did notice the AC voltage / RMS adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines could work. You would need to tune the R and C values to make sure it can detect your shortest pulse. A bleeder resistor on the cap could also help with that if the current through the opto-coupler LED is too small to bleed it fast enough (or you could use a smaller cap).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMRfpX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The opto-coupler leads could go to whatever circuit you are using for detection. It might be very convenient and flexible to have the output isolated from your transformer and the load.

Comment: Yes, I see -- thank you! Is there a more "digital" way to handle it, rather than experimenting with RC values? (It would be easy if I had a stocked lab, but I don't.)

Comment: Well, you could use a comparator output to turn the opto-isolator on and off. That would make the whole thing more amenable to analysis. But there is inevitably going to be some analog nature to this problem because the current through the load is briefly zero 100 times per second (or 120 times per second in north america).

Comment: Correct -- but I don't need to detect every such short event, as long as I detect the first one within a window of approx. 2 seconds ... the rest in that interval can indeed be treated as ignorable transients, at least till I have finished the "macro" task the relay needs to process. Basically, I need to "see" the first of any number of 50ms transients, activate a relay based on that event, and 5 seconds later start looking again for the next "event".

Comment: Ah OK. It sounds like you need to condition the signal. The best way to do this would be with a micro-controller. It could be done other ways, but I think maybe a micro-controller would be best. So I am thinking that there would be an analog-ish detector (like this one) whose output goes to a micro-controller. The micro-controller would implement whatever logic or state machine you desire.

Comment: Yes, a microcontroller can do all that -- but perhaps that is much too sophisticated for the basic task of detecting and "elongating" a 50ms event sufficiently for a mechanical relay to be able to react.

Comment: Well, it is definitely possible to do pulse elongation etc using RC time constants and comparators etc. But it can get pretty complicated and you need to define your requirements very clearly ahead of time. Then if you decide to change something, you have to get out the soldering iron. If you decide to change a time or the logic with a micro-controller, then it is just a few lines of code. It is your choice, of course. But it will either be analog-ish or it will be micro-controller-ish.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I was trying to avoid the "infratructure" and learning curve for a micro-controller to do this task, and was hoping for a flip-flop or something similar to "buffer" the pulse sufficiently to activate a mechanical relay unanmbiguously.